# Foursquare herenow always return 30 items. Is there any way to get more items?

Tags: foursquare

I'm trying to get all users at same place as me (venues with a lot of people), but the endpoint https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID/herenow returns more than 30 users in count property and only 30 people in items list.

Is there any way to get all check-ins and users at same place as me?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the parameter `limit` to retrieve up to 500 users per request. use the parameter `offset` to page through more results. see [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/herenow) for more information.

Comment: So sorry. I tried this parameter, but the library I had used doesn't make the url with parameters. Your answer encouraged me to see the library code and fix it. Thank you.